# How to increase the maximum execution time of PHP

Tags: php, windows, email, smtp, xampp

https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/source/browse/trunk/smtp_validateEmail.class.php?r=2

for upto 10 or 15 emails, it's working, but for 100 emails , it's showing error as 
"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\mail\New folder\smtp_validateEmail.class.php on line 155".
can anyone explain where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

you will need to change your php.ini execution_time to bigger value. or use

```
set_time_limit(100)
```

at begining of your script to change the same value

Comment: i have increased execution_time in php from 30 to 500 . but still "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\mail\smtp_validateEmail.class.php "

Answer (score 1):

Edit value for max_execution_time in php.in file located in xampp/php/ from 30 to Higher value.

```
max_execution_time = 300;  (5 Minutes)
```

Update :

Change the variable in your email class from 30 to 300

```
var $max_conn_time = 300;
```

Try again.

Comment: i have tried it already, even if i change for 3000, it's showing the same error as "maximum execution as 30 seconds". that's y i'm confused.

Comment: Stop the server. & Restart it. Tried that too?

Comment: yeah. i have tried that many times. even restartd system :P but can't understand, from it's showing that 30 seconds.

Comment: In your email class 1 variable value already set as                var $max_conn_time = 30; Change it & try again.

Comment: i have tried it already, even if i change for 3000, it's showing the same error as "maximum execution as 30 seconds". that's y i'm confused

Comment: @sri Oh..Have you changed value for $max_conn_time in smtp_validateEmail.class.php class too?

Comment: yes, buddy i have increased all values in that file. but still same error.

Comment: Ok. Lemme have a look on your complete code. jenson555[at]gmail

Comment: thanks.( i'm giving input from a text file where more than 100 emails. )

Comment: @jeson: i have mailed my codes and sample input.